# What does the parameter protocol stand for in socket() system call?

Tags: linux, sockets, tcp, udp

http://linux.die.net/man/2/socket

> The protocol specifies a particular protocol to be used with the
>   socket. Normally only a single protocol exists to support a particular
>   socket type within a given protocol family, in which case protocol can
>   be specified as 0. However, it is possible that many protocols may
>   exist, in which case a particular protocol must be specified in this
>   manner. The protocol number to use is specific to the 'communication
>   domain' in which communication is to take place;

http://linux.die.net/man/5/protocols

> The field descriptions are:
>
> protocol the native name for the protocol. For example ip, tcp, or
>   udp.

When we are already specifying the second parameter either sock dgram or sock stream then why again do we need the protocol parameter?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are or can be many different datagram or stream protocols. 
The typical default for the AF_INET and AF_INET6 domain(when you pass 0) for a streaming protocol is TCP, and for a datagram protocol is UDP.

Another interesting protocol is [SCTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stream_Control_Transmission_Protocol), which can operate in both datagram and stream mode, so you can create an SCTP socket in either of these ways:

```
socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_SCTP);
socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_SCTP);
```

An [UDP-lite](http://linux.die.net/man/7/udplite) variant can be created with

```
socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDPLITE);
```

Note also that socket() is a general call, and can be used to create non-IP based sockets, e.g. for bluetooth, infrared, CANbus protocols which might provide different protocols that you can use.